# How to enable MVC in a WebForms project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have an existing webforms project.  I've added MVC5 from Nuget, and added the following:

```
_Viewstart.cshtml
Shared
   _Layout.cshtml
Areas
   Test
      Controllers
        TestController.cs
      Views
        Test.cshtml
```

My controller:

```
     public class TestController : Controller
    {
    [Route("Test/Test")]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
    }
```

My `Global.asax`:

```
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Yet when I navigate to `/Test/Test`, I get 404 not found.  What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I ended up adding a few things to my web.config based on the templated MVC5 project and I now have the controller method being hit and the view being located.  I'm dealing with something else now but I believe it's unrelated to MVC configuration, so I think it really is "that easy".

Comment: I am pretty sure that MVC projects can serve up WebForms pages, but not the other way around. Shoot me in the face if I'm wrong.

Comment: a lot of good information about converting and integrating here:  http://rachelappel.com/integrating-aspnet-web-forms-and-aspnetmvc

Comment: There's more to MVC than just installing the nuget package.  You have to have Razor, routing, and a bunch of other stuff installed as well.  On top of that, there's a bunch of web.config changes you need to make.  You can start with roger's message, but that's for MVC4 not MVC5 so bear that in mind.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll You are wrong. As part of [One ASP.NET](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Launch-2013/WC103), each web application project is simply ASP.NET, and you can mix and match Web Forms, MVC, Web API, SignalR all from one project. This may only be true if you use the combined project template instead of the VS 2012 templates in the New Project dialog (but I'm not sure).

Comment: Please show the contents of your `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes()` function. My guess is you are missing a `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` line. It might also have something to do with the Areas.

Comment: @mason - I have that and I'm currently in business!  See update

Comment: @SB2055 - it's very poor etiquette to say "I fixed my problem" and not explain how you fixed it.  The point of Stack Overflow is that your questions and answers don't just help you, they help others who might have the same problem and your are denying them your solution.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch as it is to assume that I won't come back and update my answer once I make sure my current issue isn't related to the MVC configuration.  Hang tight.

Comment: @SB2055 - and yet, here it is over a week later.. and still no explanation...  So your indignation seems ridiculous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at the default MVC5 web.config, adding the following to my config got me up and running:

```
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

And:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the mvc package via nuget.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/

Answer (score -2):

If you're using MVC5, the my best suggestion would be to create an entirely new project.  In ASP.NET 4.5 and MVC5, they have combined the technologies into what they call One ASP.NET.  This makes certain things easier.

Create a new ASP.NET WebForms application, then select the MVC checkbox, and possibly the WebApi checkbox if you also need WebApi (or don't if you don't need it).

Then copy all your existing webforms code from the old project to the new.  Follow this walkthrough.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/one-aspnet-integrating-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-and-web-api

If, for whatever reason you are unable to do it this way, then a more involved process would be to create the new project, then compare it to your existing project and figure out which web.config entries you need (bear in mind that there's also a web.config in the Views folder), and which nuget packages need to be installed.  I would highly suggest the first approach though, as the second is much more involved.

Comment: The link to the walkthrough is now dead.

Comment: walkthrough was moved to here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/one-aspnet-integrating-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-and-web-api